# IE8 :after psuedo element overflow not rendering

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

I've setup this jsFiddle to illustrate the problem.  I'm using CSS psuedo elements to create a pointer, that's offset the parent element.

http://jsfiddle.net/fLTFP/

It works just fine in FireFox and Webkit browsers and IE 9, but in IE 8 the pointer gets clipped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue had to do with the `filter` declaration.  It was creating a gradient, but was changing the way IE rendered the element.  Removing it fixed the clipping.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_after.asp

and notice "**Note:** For :after to work in IE8, a [<!DOCTYPE>](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp) 
must be declared."

though it works for me in ie8

Comment: I've got a DOCTYPE set on my page. XHTML 1.0.  In IE8 you can see the full indicator?

Comment: In that particular fiddle, it does work for me in Chrome, FF, IE9 and IE8, though (of course) IE7 doesn't show it at all